# for loop doesn't work inside option html tag when trying to assing variable as value through interpolation

Tags: symfony, doctrine

As i said in title i have this

```
<select id="form_test" oninput="loadTemplate()">
    <option>Template list</option>
{% for template in templates %}
<option id="test"  value="{{ template.getReport }}">
    {{ template.getTemplateName }}
</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

It shows me all template names from `{{ template.getTemplateName }}` from database. However `value="{{ template.getReport }}"` this value always returns first report from database, as If for loop won't work inside  tag.

I am using doctrine to fetch this entities from database, like this:

```
$templates = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ReportTemplate::class)->findAll();

return $this->render('report_form/reportForm.html.twig', [
    'templates' => $templates,
]);`
```

Comment: This is not a `twig` problem. You should add more details on how you fetch and assign your data from the database

Comment: Sure, so I am using doctrine to fetch this entities from database, like shown, I added fetching method to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After I deployed site on live server it started working. It's strage I still don't know what was wrong.